# Is it possible to perform a MySQL query using Phing and set the value as a property?

Tags: mysql, phing

I'm new to Phing.

I'd like to query a value in a MySQL database table, and have the value set as a property so that I can echo it out nicely to the screen.

I can see that there is a PDOSQLExecTask which would allow me to run some SQL, but I can't see how to set the returned value into a property?

The query I want to run is:
SELECT MAX(`change_number`)
FROM `changelog`;

I'd like it set into a property:

Can anyone shed any light please?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Hi chris..! you just try to use different options that you can use while asking or posting a new question, like all code must be embedded  inside of braces(you can click on {}) and etc. don't write too many paragraphs also..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have access to MySQL at command line, I went with the following solution. I'm sure it's not the best, if someone else can improve it please do!

```
            <!-- What's the latest delta that's been applied to this deployment? -->
    <exec
        command="${progs.mysql} -h${db.host} -u${db.user} -p${db.pass} -e 'USE ${db.main_db}; SELECT MAX(`change_number`) FROM `changelog`;'"
        dir="."
        checkreturn="false"
        passthru="false"
        outputProperty="latest_version_output"
    />
    <php expression="preg_replace('/[^0-9]|\r|\n/si', '', '${latest_version_output}');" returnProperty="latest_version_applied" />
    <echo msg="Latest delta applied was: ${latest_version_applied}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`PDOSQLExecTask`](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/chapters/appendixes/AppendixC-OptionalTasks.html#PDOSQLExecTask) comes with two default formatters, which will send their output to a file. To change this, you'd probably have to implement your own formatter. On the other hand, the task appears to read its SQL commands from a separate file with SQL commands, not the build file.

So on the whole, It seems to me like you might be better of writing your own task, probably using some code from the implementation of `PDOSQLExecTask` but with your own command input and result output. Unless calling the mysql command line binary is an alternative for you, in which case you could wrap up that call to redirect its output to a property using the `outputProperty` attribute to the [`ExecTask`](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/chapters/appendixes/AppendixB-CoreTasks.html#ExecTask).